# How shall we reproduce the stack in `dirs -v`?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, pushd

I have a file whose content is the output of `dirs -v`, i.e. pathnames to directories:

```
 0  ~/program_files/OS/dirs/recentVisitedDirs
 1  ~/cs/security/computer security/OS security/user management/programs
 ...
```

How would you reproduce the stack of directories, i.e. fetch the pathname for each directory, and apply `pushd` to it, without modifying the content of the file?

Here is a script which I wrote for that purpose:

```
while read line; do
    pathname="$(awk '{ $1=""; print}'<<< $line )"
    path="${pathname//\~/$HOME}"
    pushd "$path"
done < "$1"
```

But when I run

```
$ myscript ./myfile
/home/t/bin/myscript: line 13: pushd:  /home/t/program_files/OS/dirs/recentVisitedDirs: No such file or directory
/home/t/bin/myscript: line 13: pushd:  /home/t/cs/security/computer security/OS security/user management/programs: No such file or directory
...
```

Why do I get the errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your script is that your `awk` program sets the first field to the empty string.  By doing so you do not delete it, and therefore you get a space (the default output field separator) as the first character in your shell variable `path`. `pushd` can't find the directories you're feeding it due to the space at the start of the names, and that's where you get the errors from.

Instead, you may do something like

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*//' <"$1" |
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    pushd "${pathname/#\~\//$HOME/}"
done
```

The `sed` removes any initial blanks and numbers from the start of the line before `read` reads it.

As discussed in comments: The substitution `${pathname/#\~\//$HOME/}` would only replace the tilde if it occurs together with `/` at the very start of `$pathname`. To handle a lone `~`, you may have to add a separate substitution, or something like

```
case "$pathname" in
    "~")   pathname=$HOME ;;
    "~/"*) pathname=${pathname/#\~/$HOME} ;;
esac
pushd "$pathname"
```

If the input file was created using `dirs -l -p`, then the loop would be even simpler:

```
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    pushd "$pathname"
done <"$1"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `pushd "${pathname/#\~/$HOME}"` better than `pushd "${pathname/\~/$HOME}"`? I just realized that `~` may be a valid character in a filename, and `~` as tilde expansion must be the first nonblank character in a pathname.

Comment: @Tim Yes, using `/#` rather than just `#` would be safer as that would only match the tilde at the very start of the value of `pathname`. If you want to be extra certain to match the correct thing, you would probably have to match the `/` after the tilde as well: `${pathname/#\~\//$HOME/}`. I will modify my answer to do it this way.